# Does R or ArcMap can generate a map with uk address?

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, arcgis, google-maps-api-2

**I'm really new to R or ArcMap, and geospatial science**

I have some data about the UK address, the type is like

```
 PRINCES GATE, LONDON SW7
 HOLLAND PARK AVENUE, LONDON W11
```

Is there any method for R or ArcMap to plot these address on a map and classify these address by **Lower Layer Super Output Areas** of UK

If I need to use GoogleMap API to geocode these addresses, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Google ggmap and it will give you lots of tutorials in R.